# Как реализовать сферу с помощью Canvas как на примере

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Как реализовать с помощью Canvas такую же вращающуюся сферу с словами как на сайте https://jacekjeznach.com/about/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не ленись смотреть код в примере))

Вот, то что тебе нужно. Посмотрел так же в примере сайта. Тут все в одном месте - много кода (используется библиотека). У себя в проекте нужно этот код вынести в другой файл начинается с этого и до самого конца`(function(ap) { var M, K, L = Math.abs, ah = Math.sin,`

Добавил в codepen.io так как тут лимит на 30 000 знаков

**P.S:** добавь пожалуйста в вопрос метку: javascript

[Ссылка тут](https://codepen.io/070707/pen/GRxOpxQ)